# Como chamar uma classe à partir de um evento?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma classe principal, através dela chamo um *layout* com `listview`, e dependendo do clique, abre uma tela diferente com dados de clientes diferentes.

Segue um pedaço do código:

```
public OnItemClickListener chamaAtividades(){
    return(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent;

            switch(position){
                case 0:

                        setContentView(R.layout.atividade1);

                        TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barra);
                        b.setText(new String("Gastronomia"));

                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.acai3);

                        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
                        t1.setText(new String("Açaí da Praça"));

                        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
                        t2.setText(new String("Texto descritivo do acai !"));
                        Linkify.addLinks(t2, Linkify.ALL);

                        TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t3);
                        t3.setText(new String("(035)3341-6969"));
                        Linkify.addLinks(t3, Linkify.ALL);

                        TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t4);
                        t4.setText(new String("www.acaidapraca.com"));
                        Linkify.addLinks(t4, Linkify.ALL);

                        TextView t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t5);
                        t5.setText(new String("acaidapraca@hotmail.com"));
                        Linkify.addLinks(t5, Linkify.ALL);

                        TextView t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t6);
                        t6.setText(new String("facebook.com/acaidapraca"));
                        Linkify.addLinks(t6, Linkify.ALL);

                           ...
```

Neste exemplo clicando no botão 1 (`case 0`) ira chamar o *layout* `atividade1` e setar os textos e imagens acima.

Dentro de `atividade1.xml` tem um botão e queria dar uma ação a esse botão para chamar outra classe. Como faço isto?

Estava tentando no final desse código implementar algo assim:

```
                        ...

                        TextView t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t6);
                        t6.setText(new String("facebook.com/acaidaporra"));
                        Linkify.addLinks(t6, Linkify.ALL);


                            Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voltar);
                            botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            new Mapa().setVisible(true);

                        ...
```

Mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Para começares uma nova *Activity* só tens de criar um `Intent` e invocar a nova *Activity*:

```
Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voltar);
botao.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Criação do Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(AtividadeAtual.this, NovaAtividadeASerChamada.class);

        //Adição de informação extra se pretender passar informação
        intent.putExtra("variavel", valorDaVariavel);

        //Cria a nova actividade
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```